# Rails4 Mongoid inheritance + Strong Paramters +Nested attributes

Tags: inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have the following code skeleton where a `Column` embeds_many `Contents` of types `Image` and `Map`:

```
class Column
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many: contents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contents, allow_destroy: true
end

class content
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :description
end

class Image < Content
  field :src, type: String
end

class Map < Content      
  field :latitude, type: String
  field :longitude, type: String
end
```

Now I want to pass a JSON from my `Angular` view to the `columns_controller` to create a column with two contents; image and map.

I attempted passing the following hash:

```
{'column' => 'contents_attributes' => [{_type: 'Image', description: 'image description', src: 'path/to/image'}, {_type: 'Map', description: 'map description', latitude: '25.3321', longitude: '35.32423'}]}
```

the `column_params` method is:

```
def column_params
  params.require(:column).permit(:_id, contents_attributes: [:_id, _type, :description, :src, :latitude, :longitude]) 
end
```

The above raised the following error:

`Attempted to set a value for '_type' which is not allowed on the model Content.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a workaround in the mongoid gem (version 4.0.0) in the file `lib/mongoid/relations/builders/nested_attributes/many.rb` I changed the creation of the object in the method `process_attributes` at line `109` to be

```
klass = attrs[:_type].try(:constantize) || metadata.klass
existing.push(Factory.build(klass, attrs)) unless destroyable?(attrs)
```

instead of

```
existing.push(Factory.build(metadata.klass, attrs)) unless destroyable?(attrs)
```

and this solved my problem.